# Unable to find Element using PhantomJS but works well with Firefox Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, dom, xpath, phantomjs

I am using **Selenium PhantomJS WebDriver** to crawl a **DOM** element.

**Tried:**

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@class=\"_XWk\"]").getText()
```

It works well with **Firefox WebDriver** but **doesn't** works with **PhantomJS WebDriver**.

It shows **error**:

**Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Error Message => 'Unable to find element with xpath '//*[@class="_XWk"]''**

Below is the **sample code** which I tried.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class TestPhantomJs {
    public static void testSearchReturnsResults() throws Exception {
        // Create instance of PhantomJS driver
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
        PhantomJSDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
//      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
//      FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

        // Navigate to the page
        driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
        driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1124, 850));
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

        // Input the search term into the search box
        String searchTerm = "Prime Minister of India";
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='q']"));
        element.sendKeys(searchTerm);
        element.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@class=\"_XWk\"]").getText());
        System.out.println("\nFinish...");
        driver.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        testSearchReturnsResults();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because there is no such element? Google delivers different HTML depending on the browser. Print the page source and look for the element you're interested in.

Comment: Artjom B. : Thanks man. It works!.

Comment: @iNikkz: How you found that element?

Comment: @iNikkz Could you tell us how that element?